# ReactJs: Свойство refs

Tags: reactjs

В каких случаях нужно использовать свойство refs?

Comment: Например при нажатии кнопки в форме, можно собрать значения всех инпутов(через обращение к this.refs.refname.value) и отправить их.

Comment: Когда надо что-то ручками прочитать из dom, размеры, значение инпутов etc. В документации описано подробно (смотри снизу) https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html